# How do I create an account on Postfix?

Tags: email, postfix-mta

How would I go about adding an account to Postfix and secure it with a password?

I've already setup everything else, and root works.

Answer (score 4):

**The simple way to add a user is to simply add a new account on the system**. Postfix will handle the rest.

If you don't want to create a system account for the user, you should have a virtual domain set up that is not configured as a mydestination domain. For more on this, be sure to read the Postfix guide on virtual domain hosting.

See http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3912056/Adding-Users-and-Aliases-for-Postfix.htm